# VB6 Host with MFC DLL Showing Modal Dialog Incorrectly

Tags: mfc, vb6, modal-dialog, cdialog

We have a VB6 application that we have provided extended functionality through an MFC DLL. However, there's a specific problem with CDialog-based classes in the DLL. We pass in `Me.hWnd` from the VB6 app's main form to give to the CDialog constructor so that `DoModal()` knows what its parent is. Although the CDialog-based classes are staying on top of the VB6 app on `DoModal()`, they do not **block** the VB6 app the way that's expected by a modal dialog. That is, while the DLL dialog remains in front of the EXE's window, I can still click the button that called the DLL, showing the dialog again (and again).

There's not much to show from the VB6 code. As I mentioned it just passes in `Me.hWnd`. The MFC code is simple enough:

```c
HWND exeHwnd = pSessionContext->GetHWnd(); // our state container for the DLL
CWnd* exeWnd = CWnd::FromHandle(exeHwnd);
MyCDialog dlg(exeWnd);
INT_PTR result = dlg.DoModal();
// waits, stays in front, but does not "block" the window
switch (result) // ...
```

I traced the values along the way and confirmed window handles with Spy++. Everything seems to be fine. Any ideas what I'm missing or doing wrong?

ADDITIONAL INFO

That hwnd value is used elsewhere for MessageBox and works as expected.

Comment: `pSessionContext->GetHWnd` returns VB6's `Me.hWnd`?

Answer (score 1):

A simplistic solution might be to disable the parent VB6 app in the VB6 code just before calling the DLL, and when the DLL code returns re-enable the VB6 app. Something like this (air code)

```
Me.Enabled = False 
MagicDLL.ShowTheDialog(Me.hWnd)
Me.Enabled = True
```

Comment: Though there would still be the change in window highlighting due to the loss of focus, this technique would resolve the main issue. Good workaround.

Comment: I hope someone can suggest a better fix! :)

Comment: It's nothing short of hack-tastic, but another solution is to create a dummy parent CDialog in the DLL, which then launches the real CDialog modally.

Comment: Sometimes hacktasticness is needed to get the job done! Another possible avenue of investigation: every VB6 app has a hidden top-level window "ThunderMain". You could try passing the hWnd of that window and see what happens. Here's how to find it [Karl Peterson article](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2009/11/16/no-such-thing-as-a-windowless-vb-app.aspx)